# Prevent the "program stopped working" message on a CreateProcess

Tags: c, winapi

I create a child with CreateProcess and wait for it to finish. This process is very likely to crash. Is it possible to prevent the "%PROGRAMNAME% stopped working" dialog for the child?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the child your own code (ie, is source available which you can modify)? If it is, you can catch unhandled exceptions and exit - use the [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

If it isn't, then you could attach to the process as a debugger (CreateFile with DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS) and run a simple event loop (see [MSDN on topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

I seem to recall there's a system-wide registry key to disable the default SEH dialog, but I can't find it, so I could be mistaken. Would this be too coarse for your situation?